# Adding object through REST API not appearing on chatter?

Tags: api, chatter, c#, rest

So my problem is that when i create an item, for example a new contact, which is related to an Account, the action of creating that object doesn't get shown on the chatter feed for that account.

I am using the REST API and wondering if I need to start using the CHATTER REST API or if there is some sort of parameter that needs to be set so that these actions are shown on the chatter?

I can show an example of the JSON I post with the request if that would help.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT::

To specifiy, I am creating a contact object, then adding via the REST API. Do I need to be creating a feeditem and adding via the CHATTER REST API

Comment: The record has been created but it's not showing on chatter is it?

Comment: that is correct

Comment: you need to use @mention, where mention refers to the user you want to notify. take a look at this, http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1545/how-can-i-add-an-mention-when-creating-a-feeditem-via-apex

Comment: isn't 'mention used to specifically notify a certain user about a change, whereas I just want to add an item to the chatter feed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you see a feed item for creating a record in the web UI, it's done through a publisher action (also called a Quick Action). In the API, you need to use a Quick Action endpoint to achieve the same functionality. See the [SObject Quick Actions](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_rest/Content/resources_sobject_quickactions.htm) documentation, which gives an example of creating a contact on an account using a Quick Action via the Salesforce REST API.

Comment: yea cheers i was just about to post that i found it. It seems very annoying that you can only then specify certain details about an object using quick action. At the moment i'm adding the record, and then immediately updating to specify more details about an object. Do you know of any other way to do this?

Comment: I think that's the only way that you can update additional properties on the record. The input properties for posting Quick Actions are limited to the ones that are included on the action's layout.

Comment: Okay that's a shame. Thank you very much for your help