# I want to pre-fill the Chatter Publisher

Tags: apex, visualforce, chatter, publisher

I want to create a global action that is a way for staff to Chatter a simple weekly update about what they've been working on and what they're going to work on next week. Basically, all I want is to have a chatter publisher window pre-filled with some template text:

> What did you do?
>
> •
>
> What are you going to do?
>
> •

If I create a global action, I made a VF form and generate a Chatter post with the update text, but I lose the ability to create @mentions, which are really helpful in updates.

The simplest thing would be to generate a standard chatter publisher and pre-fill it with text, then let the user start modifying. I don't think there is any way to do that on the platform. I suspect the best thing I could do is create a Google Chrome extension that allows the user to pre-fill the publisher on the client, but that's less than ideal.

Any suggestions for how I might give the user some text in the publisher so they're not starting from scratch and don't lose all the good stuff of the standard Chatter publisher?

Answer (score 3):

I think VF is your best/only bet in this circumstance, but you can do @mentions if you use the ConnectAPI, and the Chatter team released a helper class to make it much easier to invoke - see [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1545/how-can-i-add-an-mention-when-creating-a-feeditem-via-apex/11160#11160)

Comment: While you can @mention using the API, you can't really replicate the interaction you get when you start to type @[Someone].